# Changing TextColor in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good Day Everyone. I want to change the text color of the Labels in my Xamarin.Forms project. I've already tried using FontColor but it didn't work.

Here's where I want the text color to be changed. I want the **Name** and the **Department** to be color Yellow. Can you please teach me how? Thanks a lot.

```
        <Label Grid.Column="1"
          Text="{Binding Name}"
               FontSize="24"/>

        <Label Grid.Column="1"
               Grid.Row="1"
              Text="{Binding Department}"
               FontSize="18"
               Opacity="0.6"/>
```

Comment: the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Label/) site shows all of the properties, methods, events, etc for every control.  If you look at the list of properties, TextColor would be the pretty obvious choice, and you would also see that FontColor is not a valid property name

Comment: To follow up on Jasons comment, Xamarin Studio has IntelliSense for available properties and fields when editing a Xaml file. Press Command+Space to show it.

Comment: @Jason Alright Sir. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`TextColor`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Label.TextColor/) property:

**Using a color:**

```
TextColor="Yellow"
```

**Using a binding:**

```
TextColor="{Binding MyTextColor}"
```

Comment: It worked! I don't know it's just as simple as that. Thanks Man.